# OpenCL *open source* Sorting Code that *does not* require input size to be multiple of 2

Tags: sorting, cross-platform, opencl

I am looking for an opensource OpenCL sorting code. the ones available with AMD, Intel and NVIDIA SDK require the input size to be multiple of 2. Bolt library on the other hand is only restricted to AMD platforms.
Can anyone point me to such code? thanks

Comment: You can always look at one of "multiple of 2 needed" version and augment the original array by negative or positive infinity element.

Comment: Augmenting a very huge array would also consume a lot of time that's why i am looking for an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

The open-source [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/boostorg/compute) C++ library (which is built on OpenCL) has a [`sort()`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/sort.html) function and can sort any arbitrary number of values on the GPU.

Comment: I took a look at the library and I wanted to know if it can be merged with the already written code in OpenCL C and not C++? or do i have to change the already written code?

Comment: Yup, you can use it with previously developed OpenCL C code. One of the goals I strived for was to keep the OpenCL API wrapper as "thin" as possible to ease interoperability with plain OpenCL code. Take a look at (https://github.com/kylelutz/compute/blob/master/example/black_scholes.cpp#L71) to see how to embed OpenCL C kernel code in C++. You can also directly load OpenCL C code from `.cl` files with the `program::create_with_source_file()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Another open-source alternative is [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) (MIT License). It provides [sort()](http://ddemidov.github.io/vexcl/namespacevex.html#a0ee2afe5ab14567e3900ecea19e46c78) and [sort_by_key()](http://ddemidov.github.io/vexcl/namespacevex.html#a6c0d7aa078f1ae079e3a06708d9b84b6) functions. See [sort.cpp](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/blob/master/tests/sort.cpp) for the examples.